# Reactjs-rails payment method we g stripe

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Unable to collect payment using react and rails with stripe

I have followed the documentation but that's my first time trying to implement a payment method I still don't figure even how to show the ui of the form from stripe in my browser

Comment: Stripe won't have any tutorial specific to your framework/gem in this case. What I would recommend is following their integration guide for React https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements&client=react first and then figuring out how to use this in your environment afterwards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.